# How to enable AG in vim + fzf

Tags: vim, ag, fzf

I am new to vim. I read online that one of the best fuzzy finder in vim is fzf. I have started using it. But whenever I write the command :Ag I get `ag is not found`. I don't know what it means and I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to install [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), in case you are on a mac:

```
brew install the_silver_searcher
```

As another option for testing [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) you could also use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> to call `:Files` by using this map:

```
nnoremap <c-p> :Files<CR>
```

And you could  use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) when calling `:Files`, for this you will need to modify the default `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND`:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='rg --files --no-ignore --hidden --follow --glob "!.git/*"'
```

You can find more information here: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#usage

Answer (score 14):

1. By default, fzf uses the system's "find" command. You can change that by altering the env variable $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND to a third-party utility. The advantage to using these tools is that they observe ignore files. Using silver searcher (i.e. ag), you're default command would look something like the following:

   `$echo $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND 
   ag -l --path-to-ignore ~/.ignore --nocolor --hidden -g ""`

   Regardless of the FZF command used, at the shell you're gathering up *file   names* that match your criteria.
2. FZF+Vim, an extra plugin in addition to fzf, provides an :Ag command to use in (g)vim. The :Ag command lets you search the *contents* of files, opposed to its :Files command, which only searches file names.

   There is some .vimrc customization one might want when using FZF+Vim. For example, the tweak I like is the option to run :Ag with a full screen search and preview window (use :Ag! instead of :Ag):

   `command! -bang -nargs=* Ag
   \ call fzf#vim#ag(<q-args>,
   \                 <bang>0 ? fzf#vim#with_preview('up:60%')
   \                         : fzf#vim#with_preview('right:50%:hidden', '?'),
   \                 <bang>0)`

Answer (score 7):

To have a preview window for the file under cursor during search, you can add below to the *.vimrc or init.vim*

```
command! -bang -nargs=* Ag
  \ call fzf#vim#grep(
  \   'ag --column --numbers --noheading --color --smart-case '.shellescape(<q-args>), 1,
  \   fzf#vim#with_preview(), <bang>0)
```

Then use `:Ag mySearchTerm` to see the result with a preview on the right side.

You can also map `ctrl-g` to it for convenience:

> `map <C-g> :Ag`